# Creating a customer-order monthly report

Tags: sql, oracle

The report must include the following information: customer’s name, complete address, old balance, new balance and number of items that have been ordered by that customer during that period(31-Mar-2019).assuming that current balances shown are correct as of the end of February 2019.

This is what I have tried so far, it just displays the orders on that month but I having trouble including the old balance and new balance of question. I feel it is still far off from what is required.

```
select c.name, c.address, c.balance, i.qty 
from customer c, "order" o, order_item i  
where o."date" <='31-Mar-2019';
```

These are the tables I am working with

oracle sql

```
create table customer (  
    name varchar(100) primary key, 
    address varchar(200), 
    balance integer); 

create table "order" ( 
    order_no number primary key, 
    "date" date, 
    cust varchar(100),
    foreign key(cust) references customer(name)); 

create table order_item ( 
    order_no number, 
    item_name varchar(100), 
    qty number,
    primary key (order_no,item_name),
    foreign key(order_no) references "order"(order_no)
);
```

Each customer must be included only once in the result (i.e. as one row), and the results must be in ascending order of account number.

Comment: Hint: `JOIN`/`ON`.

Comment: I guess `c.balance` in the current query is current balance? What are the rules to generate the balances you want?

Comment: it's not clear ......  balance column of customer table......  how to manage this column's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model has serious issues.

A balance is normally an amount of money. However, although your `order_item` table has a `qty` there is no associated cost. Consequently it is impossible to calculate the new balance from the data provided structures. It seems you have a missing table - `item`? - which has this crucial piece of information.

Also, it is nonsense to have the concept of a "current" balance without any notion of when that balance was last calculated. We're just supposed to know it was *"correct as of the end of February 2019"*.

Also, using things like `customer.name` as a primary key is poor. Primary keys should be immutable and people often change their names.

Finally, using Oracle key words like `"order"` and `"date"` for names is unspeakable. Don't force people to enclose the object names in double-quotes. Just don't. Choose sensible names instead.

Anyway, let's get to work:

```
select c.name
       , c.address
       , c.balance as current_balance
       , sum(oi.qty) as total_items_ordered
       , c.balance + (oi.qty * i.price) as new_balance
from customer c
     join "order" o on o.cust = c.name
     join order_item oi on oi.order_no = o.order_no
     join supplier i on i.name = oi.item_name 
 where o."date" <='31-Mar-2019'
 group by c.name
       , c.address
       , c.balance;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand your questions, the Missing table you're referring to is  the Supplier Table it has the following details..  ```sql create table supplier( 
name varchar(100), 
item varchar (100), 
price float(10), 
primary key (name,item),
);

Comment: I believe the Lecturer used the Oracle Key words a way to throw the students the off. On the primary keys issue, we are not allowed to have primary keys such as numbers/integers hence the composite primary keys. I will display your query in the next comment.Kind Regards